# how to get the type of a scale in D3?

Tags: d3.js

If I create two scales:

```
a = d3.scale.ordinal()
b = d3.scale.linear()
```

How can I know which is ordinal and which is linear? Something like `d3.scale.isOrdinal(a)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no direct way to know i.e. there is not a property of the scale functions that tells you which *type* of scale it is.

The best way to do it is to test for the scale *interface* by checking for the presence/absence of any configuration method present in one of the types and not the other.

For instance:

```
typeof a.rangePoints === "function"
typeof b.rangePoints === "undefined"
```

The ordinal scale exposes a rangePoints function while the linear scale doesn't

Comment: Check the domain object type to determine time scales. scale.domain()[0] instanceof Date

Answer (score 12):

Add your own type property when you create the scale:

```
var scaleType = {
    LINEAR: "LINEAR",
    POWER: "POWER",
    LOG: "LOG",
    ORDINAL: "ORDINAL"    
};

var scale_a = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([1,2,3])
    .range([0,100]);
scale_a.type = scaleType.ORDINAL;

var scale_b = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([0,100]);
scale_b.type = scaleType.LINEAR;
```